# get value of id of hidden element by name in javascript<input id="qw" type="hidden" value="asdfg" name="1">

Tags: html

```
<input id="qw" type="hidden" value="asdfg" name="1">
```

in javscript i write
    var id_val=document.forms[frm_name][1].getAttribute('id');
but this returns null
the desired answer is "qw"
**any help will greatly be appreciated.**
Thanks in advance
Swapnil

Comment: can you post your html form ?

Comment: <input id="qw" type="hidden" value="asdfg" name="1">

Comment: well the form name is frm_name i think this should do

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have form tag in your html, also the index is start from zero. So if you refer to index 1, please check again if your form have more than one child element.

If your form has only one element, the script should be :

```
   var id_val=document.forms['frm_name'][0].getAttribute('id');
```

Comment: <form name="frm_name" method="post" action="ascc">

Comment: <input id="qw" type="hidden" value="asdfg" name="1">

Comment: okay..i miss something, I just edited my answer to add quotes for the form name